# Errors getting Amazon SNS/Cognito to register DeviceTokens on iOS - Objective-C

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

So I followed this very helpful guide https://medium.com/aws-activate-startup-blog/a-guide-to-amazon-simple-notification-service-mobile-push-self-registration-for-ios-a2502e8d5fbd#.99xqlwovh on getting SNS and Cognito to work with my application. The only thing I want it to do is register new Device Tokens as endpoints on installs.

I followed the guide exactly and I'm getting some errors. Hopefully somebody can help me out.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(nonnull NSData *)deviceToken
{

    /* This is the code to actually register the device with Amazon SNS Mobile Push based on the token received */

    NSString * myArn = @"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789123:app/APNS_SANDBOX/AmazonMobilePushExample";

    NSLog( @"Submit the device token [%@] to SNS to receive notifications.", deviceToken );

    AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput *platformEndpointRequest = [AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput new];
    platformEndpointRequest.customUserData = @"MyUserID;iPhone5";
    platformEndpointRequest.token = [self deviceTokenAsString:deviceToken];
    platformEndpointRequest.platformApplicationArn = myArn;

    AWSSNS *snsManager = [[AWSSNS new] initWithConfiguration:configuration];
    [snsManager createPlatformEndpoint:platformEndpointRequest];


    /* End Amazon SNS Mobile Push self registration */
    NSLog(@"Device Token is : %@", deviceToken);
}
```

There error is here:

```
AWSSNS *snsManager = [[AWSSNS new] initWithConfiguration:configuration];
    [snsManager createPlatformEndpoint:platformEndpointRequest];
```

Im getting "No visible @interface for 'AWSSNS' declares the selector 'initWithConfiguration'."

These are my headers, which should be fine.

```
#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>
#import <AWSCognito/AWSCognito.h>
#import <AWSSNS/AWSSNS.h>
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line has a bug:

```
AWSSNS *snsManager = [[AWSSNS new] initWithConfiguration:configuration];
```

`- new` is an equivalent of `- alloc` plus `- init`. You are calling two `init` methods. It should be changed to:

```
AWSSNS *snsManager = [[AWSSNS alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration];
```

Also, `- initWithConfiguration:` had been deprecated for a while, and now it's removed from the SDK. You need to use [`+ defaultSNS`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSSNS.html#//api/name/defaultSNS) or [`+ SNSForKey:`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSSNS.html#//api/name/SNSForKey:) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this problem:

I went ahead and ditched the code I was having issues with from the tutorial and followed the code exactly from this test project https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/SNS-MobileAnalytics-Sample/Objective-C. It is now working perfect and registering device tokens.